# Accessing the YouTube API from Android

Tags: android, youtube

I want to make an App that lets the user log into his Youtube Account, choose a playlist from his account and then play the Videos.

I am trying to connect to Youtube using this documentation:

- https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/android
- https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2
- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list

This is my relevant code in my MainActivity (just trying to get any reaction from the YT API):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // ...

    btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[]{"com.google"},
                   false, null, null, null, null);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
        }});
}

 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {        
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {

        // ...

        case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null
                    && data.getExtras() != null) {
                Log.i("VWL", "Callback");
                String accountName = data.getExtras().getString(
                        AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);

                if (accountName != null) {                        

                    credential =
                            GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Collections.singleton(YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_READONLY));

                    credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);

                    YouTube y = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential).setApplicationName("VideoWhiteList").build();

                    try {
                        Log.i("VWL", "Playlist: " + y.playlists().list("snippet").setMine(true).execute().size());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }                  

                    Log.i("VWL", "Account picked!");
                } else {
                    Log.i("VWL", "Something's fishy!");
                }
            }
            break;

    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="x.y.z">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name="x.y.z.MainActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The AccountPicker appears, and I can choose my Account. After that, I get the following error when trying to access the YT API via the `y.playlists().` line

```
02-24 11:19:27.535 3379-3379/? E/ExceptionHandler: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {x.y.z/x.y.z.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null
```

Any hints?

Comment: Could you firstly wrap your switch with this code `if(resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED)` . The error line which you have provided is because the result code is null. I'm not sure why it is null although yet.

Comment: I added: 
`if(resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED){  Log.i(TAG, "Resultcode: " + resultCode + "(" + RESULT_CANCELED + ")");     `
The Resultcode is "-1", which is RESULT_OK.
The exception is still the same.

Comment: Marc when you registered for an API Key from youtube did you provision it as an Android key? This is beacuse sometimes access may not be configured if you created a key for browser request and such

Comment: Speaking of the API Key... I have an API Kay for Youtube, but it looks like I don't use it in my code (except for filling a final variable with it). Where would I have to tell the code about the key?

Comment: I'll be honest I've not worked with the youtubev3 api but I'd suggest you take a look at this [link] (https://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-youtube-api-to-embed-video-in-an-android-app/). It's not exactly authenticating with GoogleOAuth but I'm not sure if the youtube key has to be initialized in this same manner as well. It may not apply int this situation but I just referred to it since like you mentioned I couldn't find any example where the declared final api key was being used in code